# Show that if a bipartite graph is $k$-connected, then it has a matching with $k$ edges.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Can anybody help me with proving the following?

"Show that if a bipartite graph is $k$-connected, then it has a matching with $k$ edges."

Here's my attempt at using induction on $k$:

It's obviously true for 1-connected bipartite graphs.

Let $G$ be a $k$-connected bipartite graph.
$G$ has an edge $uv$.
Let H be a graph obtained from $G$ by removing vertuices $u,v$.

Here's my problem: I don't know how to prove that $H$ is $(k-1)$-connected.

If I know $H$ is $(k-1)$-connected then by induction hypothesis $H$ has a matching $M$ with $(k-1)$ edges.
Then $M \cup \{ uv \}$ is a matching in $G$ with $k$ edges.

Or maybe you can prove it without induction?

Comment: Are you familiar with Menger's Theorem?

Comment: I am. Now I realize how easy it easy. I can just pick 1 edge from each of $k$ independent paths, that exist by Menger's theorem. Thanks.

Comment: @Dilettante  Menger theorem shows that if G is $k$-connected iff for every $u, v ∈ V (G)$
there exist at least $k$ internally disjoint $u, v$-paths in $G$.  But if there are at least two paths of length $2$ of the $k$ independent paths,  can you guarantee that the edges  that you pick will form a matching?