# Find the relationship between vertex connectivity and mathcing number.

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, graph-connectivity

> Some standard concepts:
>
> - The *vertex connectivity* of a graph $G$, written as $κ(G)$, is the smallest number of vertices whose deletion from $G$ disconnects $G$.
> - The *matching number* $\alpha'(G)$ of graph $G$, sometimes known as the edge independence number, is the size of a maximum independent edge set.

I see an interesting question from the following link.

- [Show that if a bipartite graph is k-connected, then it has a matching with k edges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902926/show-that-if-a-bipartite-graph-is-k-connected-then-it-has-a-matching-with-k)

This “result” implies the following assertion:

**Claim.** Let $G$ be a bipartite graph. Then $\kappa(G) \le \alpha'(G)$.

I see a comment of **Dilettante** on the post in the above link.

> I am. Now I realize how easy it easy. I can just **pick 1 edge from each of k independent paths**, that exist by Menger's theorem.

I have a confusion about this statement. Menger theorem shows that if $G$ is $k$-connected iff for every $u,v∈V(G)$ there exist at least $k$ internally disjoint $u,v$-paths in $G$. But if there are at least two paths of length $2$ of the $k$ independent paths, the above selected scheme does not seem to say that these $k$ edges must form a matching.

So what is the correct proof of the claim?

Moreover the difinition of bipartite graphs also appears not to have been used. So my further question is:

**Question.**  Let $G$ be a graph. Does the inequality $\kappa(G) \le \alpha'(G)$ hold?

Is there a counterexample？

Comment: The triangle is a $2$-connected graph, but its matching number is $1$.

Comment: haha, it beats all！

Comment: @kabenyuk But if we can find a class of counterexamples, that may be more convincing. So that means that for any vertex-connectivity $\kappa$, is there a counterexample? This fits as a new problem.

Comment: Yes, of course. The complete graph $K_{n+1}$ is $n$-connected, but its matching number is $[(n+1)/2]$, which is of course less than $n$.

Comment: Excellent. I post a new question. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526342/given-an-arbitrary-vertex-connectivity-kappa-is-there-a-graph-that-satisfies?noredirect=1&lq=1 ) You can answer that. I feel the complete graphs are too special. But it's enough to answer the question.

Comment: Maybe it's a good problem to figure out which graphs satisfy this inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the bipartite case for you. I do agree that the proof given in the linked question is probably not correct. For the general case, I'm not sure.

**Claim**. Let $G$ be bipartite with partitions $G = (A,B)$. Then $\kappa(G) \leq \alpha'(G)$.

Consider all separating sets of $G$ of cardinality $k=\kappa(G)$. Assume first that there exists a separating set $S \subseteq V(G)$ of cardinality $k$ that is not equal to one partition, ie. $S \neq A$ and $S \neq B$.

This means that in $(G - S) \cap A \neq \varnothing$ and similarly, $(G - S) \cap B \neq \varnothing$. Choose a vertex $a \in (G - S) \cap A$ and $b \in (G - S) \cap B$. Since $S$ is a separating set, $a$ is not adjacent to $b$. By Menger's theorem, there exists $k$ interally disjoint paths between $a$ and $b$. As you noted, this proof fails if there are paths with length $2$. Yet each $a-b$ path has length $\geq 3$ because $a$ and $b$ are non-adjacent and lie in different partitions.

If for instance, $S = A$, then first note that $|A| \leq |B|$, otherwise $B$ would be a separating set of cardinality $<k$. For every $s \in S$, $B \cup s$ is connected. This will imply $G$ is a complete bipartite graph. By Koning's theorem, the matching number of a bipartite graph is the size of the minimum vertex cover, and the size of the minimum vertex cover of a complete bipartite graph is the size of the smaller partition. This will give $\kappa(G) \leq \alpha'(G)$.

Comment: Nice! Finding a counterexample (or prove) for general graphs may be also interesting.