# Given an arbitrary vertex connectivity $\kappa$, is there a graph that satisfies $\kappa(G) > \alpha'(G)$？

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, graph-connectivity

The problem described in the title comes from my previous question:

- [Find the relationship between vertex connectivity and mathcing number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525964/find-the-relationship-between-vertex-connectivity-and-mathcing-number?noredirect=1#comment9509893_4525964)

I think it is necessary to take it as a new problem.

For bipartite graphs, as **koifish** proved in the answer, the following statement is true.

**Theorem 1.** Let $G$ be a bipartite graph. Then $\kappa(G) \le \alpha'(G)$.

If we remove the "bipartitity" in Theorem 1, we'll find some counterexamples.

The simplest example is found by **kabenyuk**:

- The triangle is a 2-connected graph, but its matching number is 1.

And then I found some other examples.

- the complete graph $K_4$ ($3=\kappa(K_4)> \alpha'(K_4)=2$).
- The following graphs satisfy that  $\kappa(G) > \alpha'(G)$.

[image]

So I thought of the following question.

**Question.** Given an arbitrary vertex connectivity $\kappa$, is there a graph that satisfies  $\kappa(G) > \alpha'(G)$？

Maybe we need to find a way to construct such graphs.

**Edits:** I was just reminded by  **kabenyuk** that complete graphs are sufficient to solve this problem. It is. The matching number for any graph with $n$ vertices is at most $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$. But the vertex connectivity can be much larger than $\frac{n}{2}$.

So a better problem is to **characterize  which non-bipartite graphs  satisfy the inequality $\kappa> \alpha'$**.

Ps:

> The vertex connectivity of a graph $G$, written as $κ(G)$, is the smallest
> number of vertices whose deletion from G disconnects $G$.

> The matching
> number $α′(G)$ of graph $G$, sometimes known as the edge independence
> number, is the size of a maximum independent edge set.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcUZh.png) is another example of a graph with $\kappa(G)=4$ and $\alpha'(G)=3$ :)

Comment: Wow, happy surprise! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove the following theorem, which tells us considerably more about such graphs:

**Theorem.** If $\kappa(G) > \alpha'(G)$, then $\alpha'(G) = \lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$: a maximum matching leaves at most one vertex of $G$ unmatched.

**Proof.** Suppose $\alpha'(G) = \frac{n-k}{2}$, so that a maximum matching has $k$ unmatched vertices, and that $k \ge 2$. Then by the [Tutte–Berge formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte%E2%80%93Berge_formula) there is a set of vertices $U$ such that $G-U$ has $|U|+k$ odd components. This is, in particular, *multiple* odd components: so $\kappa(G) \le |U|$, because $G-U$ is not connected. Also, $G-U$ must have at least $|U|+k$ vertices, so $n-|U| \ge |U|+k$, or $|U| \le \frac{n-k}{2}$. In summary, $$\kappa(G) \le |U| \le \frac{n-k}{2} = \alpha'(G).$$ Therefore if $\kappa(G) > \alpha'(G)$, then $k \le 1$ and so $\alpha'(G) \ge \frac{n-1}{2}$.

---

In fact, we don't need as strong an inequality as $\kappa(G) > \alpha'(G)$: if $\kappa'(G) > \alpha'(G)$, or even if $\delta(G) > \alpha'(G)$, then we can already conclude that $\alpha'(G) = \lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$.

For this, we use the Tutte–Berge formula more carefully. As before, suppose $\alpha'(G) = \frac{n-k}{2}$ with $k\ge 2$, and take any set of vertices $U$ such that $G-U$ has $|U|+k$ odd components. Now, additionally, let the smallest odd component have $2j+1$ vertices.

Then $$\alpha'(G) = \frac{n-k}{2} \ge \frac{|U|+(2j+1)(|U|+k)-k}{2} = (j+1)|U| + jk$$ whereas $\delta(G) \le |U|+2j$: this is the maximum possible degree of a vertex in the smallest odd component. The inequality $\delta(G) > \alpha'(G)$ rearranges to $j(|U|+k-2) < 0$, contradicting our initial assumption that $k \ge 2$.

---

This is not a characterization, but I think that there will be no good description beyond this. For example, if you take a random $n$-vertex graph with edge probability $\frac12 + \epsilon$, then with high probability $\alpha'(G) = \lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$ and $\kappa(G) = \kappa'(G) = \delta(G) \approx (\frac12 + \epsilon)n$. This gives lots and lots of boring examples.

Comment: A typographical error ($\kappa(G)$  not $\kappa'(G)$).  But it reminds me of a question: do we still have your result  for edge connectivity and matching number?

Comment: Fixed the typo. And, it looks like we can prove that result similarly: the structure that the Tutte–Berge formula gives us also helps us find a small edge cut.